# How to create floors and rooms an hostelmanagement system using Django

Tags: django

I am attempting a Hostel Management system using Django. The system can allow a user to register tenants and assign them a room on a specific floor.
I want to create a hostel in the django-admin with 5 floors, and each floor has 50 rooms. How can I add the floors and rooms to the models.py?
I am not that well experienced with Django, your responses will really help me learn a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could start with something like

```py
class Hostel(models.Model):
    pass  # maybe add `name`, etc?


class Floor(models.Model):
    hostel = models.ForeignKey(Hostel, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    floor_number = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("hostel", "floor_number"),)


class Room(models.Model):
    floor = models.ForeignKey(Floor, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    room_number = models.IntegerField()
    # you might add `capacity`, etc. here

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (
            ("floor", "room_number"),
            ("floor__hostel", "room_number"),
        )
```

The `unique_together` clauses ensure that

- no hostel has two floors with the same number
- no floor has two rooms with the same number
- no hostel has two rooms with the same number (though depending on your business requirements, this may not be required)

Then you'd probably want a management command or other script to seed these:

```py
hostel = Hostel.objects.create()
for floor_number in range(1, 6):  # Floors from 1 to 5
    floor = Floor.objects.create(
        hostel=hostel, floor_number=floor_number
    )
    for room_number_in_floor in range(1, 51):  # Rooms from 1 to 50 per floor
        # Translate floor 1, room 10 into 110, etc.:
        room_number = floor_number * 100 + room_number
        room = Room.objects.create(
            floor=floor, room_number=room_number
        )
```

and there you go! Good luck. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's really helpful. :)